# Representing Price in a Mapping

Tags: solidity, mapping

I want to use a mapping that stores prices for each token in my ERC721 contract but am hitting an issue with the default uint value being 0. I'd like for my `getPrice(uint256 tokenId)` function to account for both a zero value price and an empty value if possible. I'm wondering if there are any patterns in practice that solve this issue.

```
    mapping (uint256 => uint256) listing;
    
    function getPrice(uint256 tokenId) {
        // will return 0 for no value found, which could lead to the perception that the price is 0.
        return listing[tokenId];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The default value is always gonna be zero.

One thing you can do is write an if else statement and see if it is 0 or not. And if it is zero then you can throw an error may be.

But it depends on how you are expecting the function to work.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you have some `tokenId → token` relation in smart-contract, depending on how you generate `tokenId` and create your listings. So when your business logic of `getPrice` should rely on whether the listing has been not created yet or the price is zero, you could check the listing first. Small example:

```typescript
contract Foo {
    // tokenId => price
    mapping (uint256 => uint256) listing;
    // tokenId => token address
    mapping (uint256 => address) listings;
    
    function getPrice(uint256 tokenId) {
        require(listings[tokenId] != address(0), "LISTING_NOT_FOUND");
        // will return 0 for no value found, which could lead to the perception that the price is 0.
        return listing[tokenId];
    }
    function createListing (uint256 tokenId, address token, uint256 price) public onlyOwner {
        listings[tokenId] = token;
        // evtl some initial price
        listing[tokenId] = price;
    }
    // ... other methods to update listing
}
```